# Pandas vs PEP style guide

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas vectorized methods allow to do a lot in a single line which leads to a longer-than-usual line. How do I reconcile the PEP guidelines with pandas long lines?

PEP recommends that python maximum line length should not be greater than 72.

Pandas lines can be like this:

```
df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] = np.where((df['TEST_HOSPITAL_CONCEPT_NAME_CLEAN']=='EO AUTOMATED ABS') & (df['UNIT_AS_EXPECTED']=='cells/mcl'),df['VALUE_EXPRESSED']*1000,df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] )
```

or

```
query = df.groupby(['TEST_HOSPITAL_CONCEPT_NAME_CLEAN', 'UNIT_AS_EXPECTED_TRANSFORMED', 'NUMERATOR','DENOMINATOR']).size().reset_index(name='COUNT')
```

I cannot modify the header names and I think using variables to shorten the names will make the code less explicit and hard to read.

Comment: Well, to be precise: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) recommends to restrict docstring and comment lines to 72 characters. PEP8's recommended limit for code lines is 79 characters.

Answer (score 8):

What you're referring to is called [**method chaining**](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining).

There are a few ways to break things up:

- Put the entire expression in parentheses (as below)
- Use `\` for line continuation with no parentheses

Example:

```
query = (df
    .groupby(
        [
            'TEST_HOSPITAL_CONCEPT_NAME_CLEAN',
            'UNIT_AS_EXPECTED_TRANSFORMED',
            'NUMERATOR',
            'DENOMINATOR'
        ]
    )
    .size()
    .reset_index(name='COUNT')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also consider putting very long subexpressions into an intermediate variable. You could for example rewrite your line:

```
df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] = np.where((df['TEST_HOSPITAL_CONCEPT_NAME_CLEAN']=='EO AUTOMATED ABS') & (df['UNIT_AS_EXPECTED']=='cells/mcl'),df['VALUE_EXPRESSED']*1000,df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] )
```

as:

```
cond = (
    (df['TEST_HOSPITAL_CONCEPT_NAME_CLEAN'] == 'EO AUTOMATED ABS') &
    (df['UNIT_AS_EXPECTED'] == 'cells/mcl')
)
df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] = np.where(
    cond,
    df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'] * 1000,
    df['VALUE_EXPRESSED'],
)
```